# How to retrieve Pull request Number

Tags: github

We all know that when a  pull request is generated in github, a number is assigned to it ( something like #1234). How do i retrieve the number using github cli. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not using the git cli, as git does not have pull-requests. Use the github cli instead? https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

Comment: I removed the [tag:git] tag and put in [tag:github] instead.